# ? Confocal ellipses and hyperbolas cover whole Euclidean plane

Tags: geometry

I need a proof that we can use confocal ellipses and hyperbolas, with given foci and given perpendicular bisector of the the line segment between the foci and given pair of rays prolonging the line segment between the foci, to cover the Euclidean plane where the ellipses and hyperbolas belong.

Comment: Do you want to cover the plane with a mixture of hyperbolas and ellipses? Or do you want to do it separately, first for hyperbolas and then for ellipses? It seems to me that in any case, you are going to have trouble covering the mid-point of the foci.

Comment: Yes thank you, I have corrected my question for clarity.

Comment: Now I don't understand it at all.

Comment: Try a simpler problem first: ask the same question about circles. The problem for ellipses and hyperbolas will likely be solved in the same manner.

Comment: @TonyK    Ah I have just drawn three lines $l, m, n$ such that $l$ perpendicularly bisects the line segment $FG$ of the given foci $F, G$ and $m$ continuing $FG$ starts at $F$ and $n$ continuing $FG$ starts at $G$.

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. However, it sounds like your are talking about the [elliptic coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system) which is one of the well known orthogonal coordinate system of the plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you only need a *cover*, and not a *partition*, things are easy: Given a pair of foci and *any* point in the plane, there exists an ellipse as well as a hyperbola through that point with the given foci.

There are three special cases. If the point lies on the line segment between the foci, the ellipse will degenerate to that line segment. If the point lies on one of the rays extending that segment, the hyperbola will degenerate to that pair of rays. And if the point lies on the perpendicular bisector between the foci, the hyperbola will degenerate to that perpendicular bisector. The endpoints are included, so if the point is one of the foci, then you get the line segment as a degenerate ellipse and the pair of rays as a degenerate hyperbola.

Reading your question closely, the special case where the ellipse degenerates to the line segment isn't covered in your question statement. But you still have the hyperbolas there, so your covering is still guaranteed. If you want a partition, not only a cover, then I suggest you use *either* ellipses *or* hyperbolas, including the corresponding special cases. So for hyperbolas you are already set, but for ellipses you'll have to include one more special case.

All of this nicely matches the [elliptic coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system) achille hui mentioned in a comment. Quoting [this image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Elliptical_coordinates_grid.svg) created by [Michael Horvath](http://isometricland.net/) (also known as [SharkD](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:SharkD)) to illustrate the situation:

[image: Illustration of elliptic coordinate system]